# MySQL query doesn't work anymore, probably wrong syntax

Tags: c++, mysql, syntax-error

I have a problem with MySQL syntax I mean the query I am using did work fine before refactoring a function, program is compiling successfully... just a query doesn't work.

I've tried to play with quotation marks and apostrophes but it's still doesn't work.
This is my query:

```
string add_query = "INSERT INTO `table`(
    `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`, `col6`, `col7`, `col8`, `col9`,
    `col10`, `col11`, `col12`, `col13`, `col14`, `col15`, `col16`, `col17`, 
    `col18`, `col19`, `col20`, `col21`, `col22`) 
    VALUES (
    NULL, '" + var1 + "', '" + var2 + "', '" + var3 + "', '" + var4 + "', '" + 
    var5 + "', '" + var6 + "', '" + var7 + "', 0, NULL, NULL, '" + var8 + "', '" +
    var9 + "', '" + var10 + "', '" + var11 + "', '" + var12 + "', '" + var13 + 
    "', '" + var14 + "', '" + var15 + "', '" + var16 + "','" + var17 + "', '" +
    var18 + "');";
```

I've got just this error:

```
Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1
```

I don't have any idea how to fix it.

All help or any idea is welcome.
Sorry for bad english, it's my second language.

//EDIT
This is my cout which works perfectly in MySQL Workbench but not through my program:

```
INSERT INTO `table`(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`, 
                    `col6`, `col7`, `col8`,  `col9`, `col10`, 
                    `col11`, `col12`, `col13`, `col14`, `col15`, 
                    `col16`, `col17`, `col18`, `col19`, `col20`,  
                    `col21`, `col22`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5', '', 
       'var6', 0, NULL, NULL,  'var7', 'var8', 'var9', ' ', 
       'var10', 'var11',    'var12', 'var13', 'var14', 'var15', 'var16');
```

Comment: You are likely not protecting SQL injections. You either need to escape your string values or use prepared statements (if they are available in C++)

Comment: Look at the `add_query` variable (use your debugger or simply `cout << add_query;`). There is probably an extra quote somewhere.

Comment: Why do you tag your question with `c++` and `mysqli` (which is php)? Is `mysqli`  really relevant to your question?

Comment: Can you print out `add_query` so we can see exactly what it contains more easily?

Comment: You have a column called 'row'? The likelihood is that your design is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry for that simple script for changing variables name etc. failed.

Comment: @t.niese I think so, it's the same error u can get in php only the difference is that in cpp u have "+" operator not "." as it is in php.

Comment: You are wide open to sql Injection and your edited insert statement doesn´t correspond with your string add_query. You should upload your table structure

Comment: @nach What makes you thinking that my insert statement doesn't correspond with my string add_query? My cout perfectly works in MySQL Workbench, but doesn't through my program. "varX" in cout means some value or empty value if there is ' '.

Comment: So the columns aren't really enumerated? You just changed them for the question?

Comment: Because in your add_query string, you have var7 before 0,NULL,NULL and in your edited query you have var7 after 0,NULL,NULL

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, statement is shorter with changed columns names.

Comment: @nacho Just different name for value example... amount and places of columns are equal to amount and places of values

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with the construction of the initial string, I'm not sure if the code included in the question is exactly the same as is in your program.

This program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string var1 = "var1",
            var2 = "var2",
            var3 = "var3",
            var4 = "var4",
            var5 = "var5",
            var6 = "var6",
            var7 = "var7",
            var8 = "var8",
            var9 = "var9",
            var10 = "var10",
            var11 = "var11",
            var12 = "var12",
            var13 = "var13",
            var14 = "var14",
            var15 = "var15",
            var16 = "var16",
            var17 = "var17",
            var18 = "var18";
    std::string add_query = "INSERT INTO `table`(\
    `row1`, `row2`, `row3`, `row4`, `row5`, `row6`, `row7`, `row8`, `row9`,\
    `row10`, `row11`, `row12`, `row13`, `row14`, `row15`, `row16`, `row17`,\
    `row18`, `row19`, `row20`, `row21`, `row22`)\
    VALUES ( NULL, '" + var1 + "', '" + var2 + "', '" + var3 + "', '" + var4 + "', '" +
    var5 + "', '" + var6 + "', '" + var7 + "', 0, NULL, NULL, '" + var8 + "', '" +
    var9 + "', '" + var10 + "', '" + var11 + "', '" + var12 + "', '" + var13 +
    "', '" + var14 + "', '" + var15 + "', '" + var16 + "','" + var17 + "', '" +
    var18 + "');";

    std::cout << add_query << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Produces this output:

```
INSERT INTO `table`(    `row1`, `row2`, `row3`, `row4`, `row5`, `row6`, `row7`, `row8`, `row9`,    `row10`, `row11`, `row12`, `row13`, `row14`, `row15`, `row16`, `row17`,    `row18`, `row19`, `row20`, `row21`, `row22`)    VALUES ( NULL, 'var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'var6', 'var7', 0, NULL, NULL, 'var8', 'var9', 'var10', 'var11', 'var12', 'var13', 'var14', 'var15', 'var16','var17', 'var18');
```

which seems to be well formed SQL, though the final semicolon is not required by some APIs.

Comment: I thought that empty variables causes that error and then is something like [..] 'var1', '', 'var3'[...]. It's working in MySQL Workbench perfectly but doesn't through my program... My cout looks similar to yours.

Comment: Did you try removing the terminating semicolon from the SQL string?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to do that and nothing changed... still the same error.